# How to access compile time cljs var metadata from a clj macro?

Tags: clojure, macros, metadata, clojurescript

I'd like to construct a ClojureScript macro (executed/compiled via Clojure) that informs it's construction of a return form based on the static, compile-time metadata of a ClojureScript var argument.

I understand it is possible to access compile-time, static var metadata from ClojureScript code (using `(meta (var varsym))`; see [this post](http://swannodette.github.io/2014/12/17/whats-in-a-var/)). But is this data accessible to the compilation process in such a way that we could access it from a macro?

Here's a rough sketch of what I'd like to do (and the question is really how you'd write `get-meta-for-varsym` below):

```
;; executed/compiled in clj, targeting cljs
(defmacro themacro
  [varsym & args]
  (let [var-meta (get-meta-for-varsym varsym)
        return-form (compile-return-form-from-metadata var-meta args)]
    return-form))
```

Comment: Unlike the JVM implementation, ClojureScript does not use `Var`s at runtime, but uses bare Javascript variables instead.

Comment: @Nathan Davis: Yup; I understand that. But ClojureScript still does create a facade that allows for static var metadata. Which is cool, and good enough for a lot of purposes.

Answer (score 6):

For this you have to use the Clojurescript analyzer:

```
(ns your-macros
  (:require [cljs.analyzer :as cljs]))

(defmacro var-data
  [sym]
  (cljs/resolve-var &env sym))
```

Then in your clojurescript file:

```
(ns your-cljs)

(def ^{:foo :bar} xxy {})

(var-data xxy)
```

The meta data will be in `:meta` key of the map.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like the overall approach, but unfortunately it's not working for me. I can get `var-data` to call `resolve-var`, but the map it returns doesn't include a `:meta` key.

Comment: Works for me. What cljs version?

Comment: I am using cljs 1.8.51